# Drupal 6 relative links in blocks

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have created a block which contains a link to another page. The block is in the footer on all pages.

```
<a href="terms_and_conditions">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

This works fine on pages with URLs of...

```
http://mywebs.localhost/site1/page1
```

The link correctly resolves to:

```
http://mywebs.localhost/site1/terms_and_conditions
```

(where 'page1' is a value in the 'URL path settings' ie using the 'paths' module to create an alias for /node/56)

But when I go to the a page which is part of the ubercart module...

```
http://mywebs.localhost/site1/cart/checkout
```

The link in the block incorrectly resolves to ...

```
http://mywebs.localhost/site1/cart/terms_and_conditions
```

Obviously I can get it to work if I use full absolute links, but I want it to work when I upload to the remote host without having to change everything.

There is quite a bit of documentation and questions about relative paths. But as far as I can tell it is to do with links within the content section of pages. Can anyone point me in the correct direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/6) function or [$base_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/6) for generating the link

```
<a href="<?php echo url('terms_and_conditions'); ?>">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?php global $base_url; echo $base_url; ?>/terms_and_conditions">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. In case anyone else has this problem, you have to enable the 'PHP filter' module. And when entering text in the block, set the 'input format' to 'PHP code'. You may also have to adjust your user permissions.

Answer (score 2):

why not just `<a href="/terms_and_conditions">Terms and Conditions</a>` ? Try to put trailing slash before your path.

Just read a comment, sorry, i see other way with allowing PHP input
`<?php print l('Terms and Conditions', 'terms_and_conditions'); ?>`

But, without php input you can use a http://drupal.org/project/shortcode, it allow to transform tokens with url to a complete link, like in WordPress.

Comment: This is imo the best way to do this as long as you have no plans to host your site in a sub folder.

Comment: the trailing slash is beautiful, fast, non-intrusive and works! Thanks